# Can't find drawable/ic_stat_ic_launcher , color/petrol

Tags: android, react-native

**The error I've got**
[image]

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
  D:\Program\ReactNative\CareNow-Denco-Mobile\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:77: AAPT: error: resource drawable/ic_stat_ic_launcher (aka vn.solidtech:drawable/ic_stat_ic_launcher) not found.

  D:\Program\ReactNative\CareNow-Denco-Mobile\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:80: AAPT: error: resource color/petrol (aka vn.solidtech:color/petrol) not found.

  error: failed processing manifest.
```

I just got this project, and trying to build but it's keep getting this not found error, the result from searching is some thing like miss copied from xml file but I don't know if that right.
Need some help pleaseeeee

---

### EDIT

This is the error show in the debug log

```
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_ic_launcher" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/petrol" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/fb_app_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.accountkit.ApplicationName"
            android:value="@string/app_name" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.accountkit.ClientToken"
            android:value="@string/ak_client_token" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />
```

Comment: Hey, share your ``AndroidManifest.xml`` file, also check into res/values colors.xml.

Comment: I just edit the question

Comment: okay , check your drawable folder, and its contain image name like "``ic_stat_ic_launcher.jpg``". if name is mismatch please rename i``c_stat_ic_launcher.jpg.``

Comment: you have ``values`` folder inside the ``res`` folder ?

Comment: can you give me some idea about what this code doing?
I totally got no idea so i don't event know how to find the drawable folder like you said

Comment: okay wait. i'll give example snaps

Comment: you have ``drawable``? folder

Comment: trying to find all folder in android studio with keyword "drawable" but got none

Comment: have you using any text editor?

Comment: i'm using visual studio and android studio

Comment: okay, please find the ``drawable`` folder below the path.. ``android\app\scr\main\res``

Comment: there now such ```drawable``` from the \res

Comment: ``mipmap`` find this?

Comment: https://imgur.com/maBAtac
here are those mipmap

Comment: but no ```ic_start_ic_launcher``` is this miss copying?

Comment: in mimap  folder contain any image?, please share image name

Comment: all the image is shown in that picture, you can see ```.png``` founded

Comment: its okay, image name?

Comment: all image name is in that image bro

Comment: @ Phaoga55, your doing couple of mistakes, please create new project with ``react-native init  project-name``.

Comment: There is no ic_stat_ic_launcher in drawable folder and no petrol value in color resource file. Add that values to make your program run

Comment: okey, thank you both.
But everytime I work with googleservice, always have to delete the build folder or the error ```Failed to delete: D:\Program\ReactNative\CareNow-Denco-Mobile\android\app\build\generated\res\google-services\debug``` keep coming. Is there anyway to fix this beside that delete?

Comment: your working directory  can't be closed properly, its maybe a problem. once you close properly, maybe u won't receive this ``Failed to delete:`` sound.